# TypeError: 'Publisher' object is not callable

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.

I am trying to publish to a topic, using python with a custom message file.

My message file name is "joints.msg" and is:

```
float32 q1
float32 q2
float32 q3
```

In my python code I have the following (as far a the publisher is concerned):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from input_suport import *
from archoff.msg import joints
.
.
.
pub_torques = rospy.Publisher('torque_topic', joints, queue_size=10)
#sub_angles = rospy.Subscriber("angles_topic", joints, get_angles)
rospy.init_node('humerus_m', anonymous=True)
rospy.sleep(1.)
.
.
.
rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        .
        .
        .
    j_speed = joints(dq[0][0], dq[1][0], dq[2][0])
    pub_torques(j_speed)      # first attempt 
    #pub_torques(1.0, 4.2, 3.2)      # second attempt
    rate.sleep()
```

As you can see above, I tried with two different ways but nothing works. I always get the message:

> TypeError: 'Publisher' object is not
> callable

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226599/typeerror:-%27publisher%27-object-is-not-callable/) by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 293 on 2016-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need to put `pub_torques.publish(j_speed)` to call the objects publish method

See http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2016-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Metalzero2](https://answers.ros.org/users/20078/metalzero2/) on 2016-02-14**:
OMG I must be blind! How did I not see that -_-. Thanks very much :)